# How can a filter expression be built up with `into_boxed()` to operate against a query with a join?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

In diesel, I want to build up the argument for `.filter()` in a programmatic way, but rust complains that `into_boxed()` cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds.

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
mod schema;
use diesel::{QueryDsl, ExpressionMethods, JoinOnDsl, NullableExpressionMethods};

fn main() {
    use crate::schema::Foo::dsl as foo_dsl;
    use crate::schema::Bar::dsl as bar_dsl;

    let mut query = foo_dsl::Foo
        .inner_join(bar_dsl::Bar
            .on(bar_dsl::foo_id.eq(foo_dsl::id.nullable())))
        .select((foo_dsl::id,)).into_boxed();

    let mut filter =  foo_dsl::id.eq(42).into_boxed();
    filter = filter.and(bar_dsl::id.eq(17));

    query = query.filter(filter);

}
```

Complains

```
Error[E0599]: the method `into_boxed` exists for struct `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:14:42
    |
14  |     let mut filter =  foo_dsl::id.eq(42).into_boxed();
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /home/ross/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/expression/operators.rs:343:1
    |
343 | diesel_infix_operator!(Eq, " = ");
    | ---------------------------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: QueryDsl`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: Table`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: Table`
            which is required by `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: QueryDsl`
            `&diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: Table`
            which is required by `&diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: QueryDsl`
            `&mut diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: Table`
            which is required by `&mut diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Foo::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>: QueryDsl`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `and_or` due to previous error
```

How can I build up a filter against a query that has a join?  [`BoxableExpression`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression/trait.BoxableExpression.html) exists, but my combined filter

```
filter = filter.and(bar_dsl::id.eq(17));
```

is not for one single table.

*This example could clearly be done without the `filter` variable and done directly in the `.filter()` call on the query.  It is an [S.S.C.C.E](http://www.sscce.org/).*

Can a boxed filter be built up somehow? With `BoxableExpression` or using `into_boxed()`?

---

schema.rs looks like:

```rust
table! {
    use diesel::sql_types::*;

    Bar (id) {
        id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        foo_id -> Nullable<Integer>,
    }
}

table! {
    use diesel::sql_types::*;

    Foo (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        label -> Text,
    }
}

joinable!(Bar -> Foo (foo_id));

allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    Bar,
    Foo,
);
```

---

*p.s.*

With hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169975/20712) by @weiznich,

It looks like I can figure out a valid [`BoxableExpression`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/i686-pc-windows-msvc/diesel/expression/trait.BoxableExpression.html) as:

```rust
    pub type QueryType = diesel::dsl::InnerJoin<foo_dsl::Foo, bar_dsl::Bar>;
    let mut filter: Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QueryType, DB, SqlType = Bool>>
        = Box::new(foo_dsl::id.eq(42));
    filter = Box::new(filter.and(bar_dsl::id.eq(17)));
```

Now, when I use that `filter` variable like

```rust
    query = query.filter(filter);
```

I get

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn BoxableExpression<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Bar::columns::foo_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>, Sqlite, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>: AppearsOnTable<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Bar::columns::foo_id, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:27:19
   |
27 |     query = query.filter(filter);
   |                   ^^^^^^ the trait `AppearsOnTable<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Bar::columns::foo_id, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>` is not implemented for `dyn BoxableExpression<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Bar::columns::foo_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>, Sqlite, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AppearsOnTable<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Bar::columns::foo_id, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>` for `Box<dyn BoxableExpression<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Bar::columns::foo_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>, Sqlite, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FilterDsl<Box<dyn BoxableExpression<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Bar::columns::foo_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>>, Sqlite, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>>>` for `diesel::query_builder::BoxedSelectStatement<'_, (diesel::sql_types::Integer,), JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Bar::columns::foo_id, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<Foo::columns::id>>>, Sqlite>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `and_or` due to previous error
```

---

*p.p.s.*

Interesting.  I can get things to compile with the `BoxableExpression` as long as I don't let the query be `into_boxed` as well.  The following compiles:

```
    pub type QueryType = diesel::dsl::InnerJoin<foo_dsl::Foo, bar_dsl::Bar>;
    let mut filter: Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QueryType, DB, SqlType = Bool>>
        = Box::new(foo_dsl::id.eq(42));
    filter = Box::new(filter.and(bar_dsl::id.eq(17)));

           
    let mut query = foo_dsl::Foo
        .inner_join(bar_dsl::Bar.on(bar_dsl::foo_id.eq(foo_dsl::id.nullable())))
        .filter(filter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following filter buildup with `BoxableExpression` works and is usable with a query that is then itself boxed with `.into_boxed()`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
mod schema;
use diesel::{QueryDsl, ExpressionMethods, JoinOnDsl, NullableExpressionMethods};
use diesel::sql_types::*;
use diesel::expression::BoxableExpression;
use diesel::BoolExpressionMethods;

use std::boxed::Box;
type DB = diesel::sqlite::Sqlite;

fn main() {
    use crate::schema::Foo::dsl as foo_dsl;
    use crate::schema::Bar::dsl as bar_dsl;

    let mut filter: Box<dyn BoxableExpression<_, DB, SqlType = Bool>>
        = Box::new(foo_dsl::id.eq(42));
    filter = Box::new(filter.and(bar_dsl::id.eq(17)));


    let mut query = foo_dsl::Foo
        .inner_join(bar_dsl::Bar.on(bar_dsl::foo_id.eq(foo_dsl::id.nullable())))
        .into_boxed();

    let query = query.filter(filter);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that based on your attempts and self-answer that you are fixated on using a single `.filter()` call and sort out the dynamicism beforehand. However, I would encourage you and future viewers to instead rely on the flexibility provided by the boxed statement created by `.into_boxed()`:

```
use crate::Foo::dsl as foo_dsl;
use crate::Bar::dsl as bar_dsl;

let mut query = foo_dsl::Foo
    .inner_join(bar_dsl::Bar.on(bar_dsl::foo_id.eq(foo_dsl::id.nullable())))
    .into_boxed();

query = query.filter(foo_dsl::id.eq(42));
query = query.filter(bar_dsl::id.eq(17));
```

This is more in line with how the developers of Diesel have designed dynamic queries to be done.

- [`into_boxed()`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.into_boxed) says: *"This is useful for cases where you want to conditionally modify a query, but need the type to remain the same."*
- [`BoxableExpression`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/expression/trait.BoxableExpression.html) says: "*For cases where you want to dynamically construct a query, boxing the query is usually more ergonomic.*"

Comment: I am aware of `query....into_boxed()` and I use that a lot.  The real issue was that I wanted to do a 2 level reduction filtering with the first level being an AND reduction and the second level being an OR reduction.  Something like  `select * from user where ( (first_name="ross" AND last_name="rogers") OR (first_name="bob" AND last_name="smith") )`  Since multiple calls to `filter` are an `AND` operation, I needed to use the boxed filter instead.

Comment: @RossRogers hmm, you might be able use [`.or_filter()`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.or_filter) for that, its the same as `.filter()` except it ORs with any filter before it.

Comment: Good to know about `.or_filter`.  In my case that wouldn't been sufficient because there is a base filter about what the user is able to access based on group membership that is always present and I can't OR that base filter with the 2nd AND-> OR reduction.  Both tools are useful and indeed boxed-query is easier, in my experience.